# Why does this regex in bash not match the line despite matching in regex tester?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sh, mingw

I am trying to match a line in `netstat` where the local port matches some port that's passed in to my script. But this regex (while it matches in a regex tester) doesn't seem to work.

```
# Get lines from netstat
IFS=$'\r\n' GLOBIGNORE='*' command eval  'NetstatLines=($(netstat -anq))'

for line in "${NetstatLines[@]}"; do

    # This never matches
    if [[ "$line" =~ ^\s*(TCP|UDP)\s+(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+:$iPort|\[::\d*\]:$iPort)\s+ ]]; then
        echo "found it!!"
    fi

done
```

The lines look like:

```
Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:623            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:2179           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5040           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:7680           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

So if `$iPort` is `135`, it should match the 4th line.

Comment: Bash uses posix EREs, not Perl style ones like that.

Comment: @Shawn Where can I find info on that syntax and a tester?

Comment: Just search for "posix extended regular expression" and you'll find plenty.

Comment: @Shawn I did but I cannot find enough information on how to translate my current regex to a posix one.

Comment: POSIX RE syntax doesn't support the `\d` and `\s` shortcuts; use `[[:digit:]]` and `[[:space:]]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Shawn and these sites:

- https://www.regextester.com
- https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html

I was able to figure it out:

```
^[[:space:]]*(TCP|UDP)[[:space:]]+([[:digit:]]+[.][[:digit:]]+[.][[:digit:]]+[.][[:digit:]]+:$iPort|[[]::[[:digit:]]*[]]:$iPort)
```

That is equivalent to the non-posix version I started with.